# Records not import successfully

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm trying to import some data into the Database by uploading an Excel file, so here is my Import Class:

```
public function model(array $row)
    {
        $member_id = DB::table('members')->where('mbr_national_code', $row[3])->value('mbr_id');
        return new ImportExamResult([
            'candidate_id' => $row[4],
            'nid' => $row[3],
            'status' => 1,
            'member_id' => $member_id,
            'olympiad_id' => 2,
            'descriptive_score' => $row[12],
            'four_choice_score' => $row[10],
            'total_score' => $row[13],
            'rank' => $row[14],
            'batch' => 1,
            'created_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
            'updated_at' => now()->toDateTimeString(),
        ]);
    }
```

Now it works fine and inserts all the data but the only weird problem is, it does not insert `rank` and `total_score`. In fact it inserts 0 however there is no data in the Excel file with `rank` and `total_score` of 0.

So what's going wrong here?

And here is the Model:

```
class ImportExamResult extends Model implements FromCollection, ShouldAutoSize, WithHeadings, WithEvents
{
    protected $table = 'import_exam_results';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['nid', 'candidate_id', 'status', 'member_id','olympiad_id','descriptive_score','four_choice_score','total_score','rank','batch']; 
    ....
```

Comment: Hello, make a var_dump($row); die(); before `$member_id = ...;` to see what `$row` contains

Comment: Probably, the database fields are integer and the default value set us 0. So that when no data comes it will be zero.  Please make sure the index of 'total_score' and 'rank' is correct. If the index is correct then check the data, string can't be inserted into integer columns. If nothing works, dump the $row data before the insertion and check it has values for the mentioned columns? what's the data type of the columns and compare it with the table column data type.